# Мне надо разделить text field на label и получить ответ в другом label

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode все время выдает ошибку: "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"    (отметил в коде "Fatal Error")
var plusAndMinus = 0

class ViewController234: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var adam: UILabel!

@IBAction func plus(_ sender: Any) {
    plusAndMinus += 1
   adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
}
@IBAction func minus(_ sender: Any) {
    if(plusAndMinus != 0 ) {
        plusAndMinus -= 1
    }
   adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
}

// Write total amonunt to calculate


@IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UITextField!

@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let adamValue = Int(adam.text!), adamValue != 0,            // Fatal error
             let totalAmountValue = Int(totalAmount.text!) else { return }   

       let result = totalAmountValue / adamValue
       finish.text = String(result)
    
}


//Show calculated
// finish = totalAmount / adam

@IBOutlet weak var finish: UILabel!



"
```

Comment: допускаю что adam не находит

Comment: 1) Разделить - это выполнить математическое деление, или просто порезать текст на части?
2) Почему везде sender: Any? Кто фактически запускает функции?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в adam.text и в totalAmount.text нет значений, поэтому при их развертывании получается nil и exception. Чтобы исключить краш, попробуйте вот так:

```
guard let adamText = adam.text, let adamValue = Int(adamText), adamValue != 0,
      let totalAmountText = totalAmount.text, let totalAmountValue = Int(totalAmountText) else { return }
```

Comment: "guard let adamText = adam.text..." => adam.text снова выдает ошибку Fatal Error: nil

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас все аутлеты соединены со сторибордами/ксибами.